# how to pass parameters to methods

Tags: java, methods

If I want to pass 3 integers read from the user to a method, is it important in which order I read these integers from the user? I mean is there a difference between this code:

```
        int small = scan.nextInt();
        int big = scan.nextInt();
        int medium= scan.nextInt(); 
        size(small, big, medium);
        //size is a method I wrote :public static boolean size(int small, int big, int medium)
```

and this code:

```
        int medium= scan.nextInt();
        int small = scan.nextInt();
        int big = scan.nextInt();
        size(small, big, medium);
```

Comment: Yes, it is important in which order to pass parameters to most methods.

Comment: But it is not important in which order you get them from the user.

Comment: Here's a suggestion.  Write a method called `size`, which prints out the three numbers.  Then try this out, and see for yourself whether there's any difference between the two snippets.  I think experimenting will help you understand this, better than reading answers on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Nope! Although you should let the user know what they are entering:

```
    System.out.println("Enter the medium value: );
    int medium= scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the small value: );
    int small = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the big value: );
    int big = scan.nextInt();
    size(small, big, medium);
```

With that being said, there could be an issue if the user enters the incorrect values (i.e. if the user enters the small value when he should enter the medium value).

Therefore, you should perform some checks before your call the method, like so:

```
int small, medium, big;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the medium value: );
    medium= scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the small value: );
    small = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the big value: );
    big = scan.nextInt();
while (!(small < medium && medium < large));

size(small, big, medium);
```

Comment: so you mean it does not matter if he entered the small value then the medium and than the big taking into consideration that i pass them in a correct order to the method.

Comment: Yes this does matter. If the user enters the small value first (when he should enter the medium value), then when you pass them into the method the medium value will be the small value. I'll update my answer to clarify

Answer (score 0):

If the user enters `10`,`20`,`30` then the first version would have the method call `size(10,20,30)` and the second would have `size(20,10,30)`. That is a difference.

Comment: but why there is a difference although i am passing the variables in the same order for the method in both version and the variable small is different than medium and different than big.

Comment: In the first version you are assigning the _first_ number the user enters to the variable `small`. In the second version you are assigning the second number the user enters to the variable `small`. It is the difference between "small is the first number" and "small is the second number".

Answer (score 0):

1.No theres no difference when setting up variables only in how you set up the method, for example this is fine no matter how you order it.

```
 int small = scan.nextInt();
 int big = scan.nextInt();
 int medium= scan.nextInt();
```

2. The call should mimic the way you have created the method you will get a syntax error, this was one of my biggest flaws when I had first started programming

   ```
   public int size(int small, int big , int medium){
   ....}
   size(small, big, medium); // correct
   size(big,small, medium);// wrong in this case
   ```

3.But you can declare the variables in any order, long as when you call the method it is in the set up in the same way in which you created your method.

```
int medium= scan.nextInt();
int small = scan.nextInt();
int big = scan.nextInt();
size(small, big, medium);
```

4.Additional Example if you wanted to call the size method in the same way as the second example you can set up the method like this:

```
public int size(int big, int small , int medium){
....} 
size(big,small, medium); // correct
size(small, big, medium); // wrong in this case
```

Answer (score -1):

you should prompt the user , so he/she can insert the right Data . mainly it has no difference unless the method itself deals directly with orders as they are .